# Embedding hidden data inside files

Tags: steganography

I need to embed a unique ID hash string in many types of files, and then verify the hash string inside the files later on remotely.

Is there a best practice for doing this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The technique is called steganography, not encryption, please search for it and add the results of your research to your question.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, it might be called "watermarking" instead.

Comment: Considering that steganography is based on security by obscurity, any best practice automatically becomes a bad practice the moment it is published.

Comment: Or maybe that's not what you are trying to do? What's the attack scenario? Finding the hash? Changing the hash? Removing the hash? And what is the data you are hashing? The file itself or something unrelated? And what kind of files are you talking about?

Comment: If this is to identify later the source of the file, it is called "watermarking". To get useful answers, you need to tell us why you are doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply embed a hash *inside* file types if the file type is not designed for that. By doing so, you will probably break the file and it cannot be used until you have undone this change.

However, you can put the hash codes into a separate file, e.g. a CSV file. Put the (relative) file name first, then the hash. Transfer all files to the target PC and check against the hash codes of the CSV file (or whatever your use case is).

If you want the hashes to be invisible for a user, place the CSV somewhere where it's not obvious and remove access rights. Note that someone with administrator rights can still take ownership of that file and modify or delete it.

Another idea: you can try putting it into an alternate data stream (ADS) if you're using the NTFS file system. However, note that ADS are removed when copying to different file system. Also note that someone who is aware of ADS can still reveal those streams, modify the content and delete them.

All above options are not secure. If you want a secure solution, your hashing approach needs to be combined with some sort of encryption.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not interested on a working file, just open the binary file and add the hash.

If you are interested on a working file, you have to look into more specialized techniques of bit-level changes that don't affect the original file.

To later verify the hash, use the command `strings`.